# Local development of AWS Synthetics Canaries Selenium

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, selenium, amazon-cloudwatch

On documentation pages for AWS Cloudwatch Synthetics Canaries we can find code samples (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_Library_Python.html#CloudWatch_Synthetics_Library_Python_UIcanaries) that include imports of "aws_synthetics.selenium" module and tools like the synthetics_webdriver or synthetics_logger.

Is there any way to install this package for the purposes of local development?
This is not the AWS CDK package aws_cdk.aws_synthetics is it?

I've searched the internet for a few days and sadly found no solution and I'm using a wacky import to work around it

```
if os.environ.get("LOCAL"):
    from selenium import webdriver
else:
    from aws_synthetics.selenium import synthetics_webdriver as webdriver
```

i would like to use the latter import locally aswell

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about local development of Lambda functions. If so, there is [documentation on AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/jump-starting-your-serverless-development-environment/) on how this is done. I can't guarantee this is appropriate for your situation.